# If $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $f ′(c) = 0$, then there exists an $h > 0$ such that $f$ is differentiable in the interval $(c – h, c + h)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

My book states the following: if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $f ′(c) = 0$, then there exists an $h > 0$ such that $f$ is differentiable in the interval $(c – h, c + h)$. But I don't understand this. It is not as if $f'$ is given to be continuous, rather $f$ is given continuous and differentiable **at $x=c$**. So how can we possibly comment about the existence of $f'$ in the neighborhood of $c$ too? Note that f is defined on an open interval I and c belongs to I.

Comment: That is not true.  $f$ can be discontinuous everywhere except at $c$.

Comment: I wanted to specify that f is defined on an open interval I, and c belongs to I.

Comment: As far as the open interval $I$ is concerned, does a piecewise function qualify here?

Comment: To expand on @user10354138 's comment: take $c=0$ and define: $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0&x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$

Comment: Many calculus textbooks designed for introductory courses have mistakes of this nature. These are not typos but a lack of understanding of concepts on part of authors. There is no dearth of such crappy books in market and usually a calculus student has to bear such books.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;g(x):\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ be the Darboux function defined as follows

$g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n!}\sin\bigl((n+1)!x\bigr)\quad\forall x\in\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\;.$

$g(x)\;$ is continuous everywhere on $\;\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\;$ and nowhere differentiable.

Let $\;c\;$ be a real number that is $\;c\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

Let $\;f(x):\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ be the function defined as

$f(x)=(x-c)^2g(x)\quad\forall x\in\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\;,\;$

then $\;f(x)\;$ is continuous everywhere on $\;\left]-\infty,+\infty\right[\;,\;$ differentiable only at $\;c\;$ and $\;f’(c)=0\;,\;$ indeed

$\begin{align}
f’(c)&=\lim\limits_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim\limits_{x\to c}\dfrac{(x-c)^2g(x)}{x-c}=\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to c}(x-c)g(x)=0\;.
\end{align}$

Since $\;f(x)\;$ is differentiable only at the point $\;c\;,\;$ there does not exist any $\;h>0\;$ such that $\;f(x)\;$ is differentiable on the interval $\;\left]c-h,c+h\right[\;.$

Hence, it is wrong what your book states about continuous functions differentiable at a point $\;c\;$ such that $\;f’(c)=0\;.$

It is wrong even if the function is continuous everywhere, not only at the point $\;c\;,\;$ that is why my counterexample is different from those proposed by other users.

Answer (score 1):

Just start with the function $Q$ that’s the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q$, i.e., $Q(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, zero otherwise.

Then take $f(x)=x^2Q(x)$, with $c=0$.

Comment: You only proposed a counterexample in the case that the function $\;f(x)\;$ is continuous only at one point, but I think it would be better to give a complete answer for everywhere continuous functions despite the OP did not asked it explicitly.

Comment: True enough, @Angelo , but a universally quantified statement needs but a single counterexample.

Comment: Yes, you are right, a universally quantified statement just needs one counterexample, but somebody could think that if the function $f(x)$ were continuous everywhere, it would necessarily be differentiable on a neighbourhood of $c,$ but it is not true.